# How to merge two dynamic array with different values in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a quiz application, not able to bring the question and answer in a array to store into DB.
Array1 contains the value of questions entered by user
Array2 contains the options value of answer entered by user

I am sharing mycode, **questions_enter** is the question getting tag.
**text_val** is contains the answers(can be many options up to user, max option 6)

```
newquesDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
    .attr("id", 'quest_id' + quest_count);


    newquesDiv.after().html('<p>'+question_enter+'</p>');

    for(var i=0;i<text_val.length;i++){

        newquesDiv.append('<input id="text'+checkbox_count+'" value="'+text_val[i]+'" type="text" name="textname" readonly/><br>');

        checkbox_count++;
    }
    newquesDiv.append('<br>')
    newquesDiv.appendTo("#questions_options");
```

**Input**

```
Array1 = ["Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"...]
Array2 = [ "a", "b", "aa", "bb", "cc".... ]
```

Need **Output** like this

```
Q1 a,b
Q2 aa,bb
Q3 cc
```

PFL ***https://jsfiddle.net/b75p929h/43/***

Comment: Please create a working snippet demonstrating where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I just found answer by myself , created dictionary in js and added all the questions and answers into it, parsed using python.

```
   quest_array.push(
        $('#enter_question').val()
    );
    last['quest_array']=quest_array

    option_array.push(
        text_val
    );
    last1['option_array']=option_array

    topics_array.push(
        topics_name
    );
    last2['topics_array']=topics_array
```